# How to multivariate regressors work?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, predictor, multivariate-regression

while I seem to understand that there is a general matrix-based formula that allows us to solve for multivariate regressors, when looking at the non-matrix solution for a bi-variate $\beta$ I realised I wasn't quite able to understand the mechanics which allows for the partialling-out of one variable or the other.

The equation I am working with is as follows:

$\beta_1=\frac{Var(x_2)Cov(x_1,y)-Var(x_1)Cov(x_2,y)}{Var(x_1)Var(x_2)-Cov(x_1,x_2)}$

Would it be possible to break down each part of this equation to explain how $\beta_1$ manages to capture just the effect of $x_1$ on $y$?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

As a disclaimer, I have opted not to solve the simultaneous equation myself as I was worried I might make an error, and have instead transcribed the solution I came across [here](http://faculty.cas.usf.edu/mbrannick/regression/Part3/Reg2.html).